# Is it possible to target .NET4.0 in Visual Studio 2015 C++/CLI projects?

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2015

I have recently installed VS2015. Yay! \o/

However, one of my C++/CLI projects showed this message when upgrading from VS2013:

> The following project(s) uses an earlier version of the Visual C++ compiler and libraries. The project(s) will be upgraded to use the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 compiler and libraries. **Any managed or native code project(s) using C++/CLI extensions will be automatically upgraded to target .NET Framework 4.5.2.** Note: If you do not upgrade the project(s), building your project(s) will require the corresponding version of Visual Studio to be installed.

I ok'd the warning, but now code which compiled previously in VS2013 no longer compiles, for instance:

```
void WritePixels(array<unsigned int> ^ rgbaData);
```

has the error

> 'std::array': too few template arguments
>   '^': cannot use this indirection on type 'std::array'

Also the project properties do not allow me to switch target .NET framework version (it is grayed out).

Is it possible for C++/CLI projects to target .NET 4.0 using Visual Studio 2015? Are there any syntax changes in C++/CLI since Visual Studio 2013 that I need to know about?

Comment: You know that `using namespace std;` is bad, do you? :-)

Comment: Microsoft does not want to support multi-targeting for C++/CLI projects.  There are a few very ugly corner-cases where the compiler will use the wrong reference assemblies, the #using directive is a problem.  Whether it is in yours is impossible to tell.   You can edit the .vcxproj file by hand and change the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>`.  But that doesn't have anything to do with the compilation error, you've got an `#include <array>` somewhere along with a `using namespace std;`.  Very fixable of course, if necessary type out `cli::array` to disambiguate.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I will go double check the vcxproj and see what we can do! For now, reverting to VS2013, which is a shame, as 2015 is very shiny!

Comment: I had a combination of errors I think. One was an SVN error which missed some C++ files meaning nothing could compile. Second was, yes I have a using namespace std; Silly me :) Third is the platform target in C++/CLI project - still working on that one. If I can get all resolved we'll be using 2015. Thanks for help!! :)

Comment: I have build a large C++/CLI code base on VS 2015 targeting .NET 4.0. It all seemed to work fine. .NET 3.5 seems to build but then gives obscure link errors. I have tried to ask MS about this, here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35e2bad4-d80d-4f73-a994-ef696e6c8f14/build-ccli-targeting-net-35-with-visual-studio-2015-linking-with-unmanaged-c?forum=msbuild is one instance but they don't seem keen!

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for posterities sake.

I solved this by workaround, by not using C++/CLI at all, but using the amazing, adaptable [SWIG Platform Invoke Generator](http://www.swig.org) library.

No C++/CLI = no issues with .NET Framework versions, no issues with x64/86 bit and .NET Any CPU.

Problem Solved ...